# Is every family of diffeomorphisms generated by a family of vector fields?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, diffeomorphism

Suppose that $\phi_t$, $t \in \mathbb R$ is a family of diffeomorphisms of a manifold $M$. It is assumed that $\phi_0$ is the identity mapping and dependence on $t$ is smooth, but $\phi_t$ is not a one parameter group: it doesn't hold that $\phi_t \phi_s = \phi_{t+s}$. The question is whether there exists a one parameter family $X_t$ with $X_0=0$ of vector fields such that $\phi_t = \exp ( X_t)$.

I suspect the answer may depend on the type of manifold. For me the two most important choices are compact $M$ and $M = \mathbb R^n$. If the answer to my question is not affirmative in general, I am interested in learning the criteria I need to impose on $\phi_t$ and $M$ to make the statement true.

Comment: Let $f_t:x\mapsto x+\pi+t\sin 2x$, which for small t is a diffeo of the line that passes to the quotient to give a diffeo of the circle views as $\mathbb R/2\pi\mathbb Z$. If t is non zero, the corresponding diffeo of the circle is not the exponential of a vector field (a self diffeo of the circle without fixed points is conjugated to a rotation, and it cannot therefore have isolated periodic points)

Comment: $f_0(x) \neq x$ in this example. I insist on families which reduce to identity mapping for some value of the parameter to avoid topologically nontrivial diffeomorphisms.

Comment: Another interesting variant of my question takes the form: is there a logarithm function defined on the connected component of the group of diffeomorphisms? In this case I would be very surprised if this logarithm could be taken as globally smooth though.

Comment: No, the exponential map is not surjective onto the connected component of the identity, and in fact is not even surjective onto any neighbourhood of the identity. [This MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/153484/33510) has a couple of nice answers that I think will be interesting to you.

Comment: Why can't you define $X_s$ to be $\partial_t \phi_t |_{t = s}$? I.e., just define $X_s$ to be the derivative of the 1-parameter family at time $t = s$. This gives a 1-parameter family of vector fields $X_s$. Needless to say, $X_t = X$ for all time $t$ if and only if $\phi_t$ is a 1-parameter subgroup of $\text{Diff}(M)$ (the intuition is to think of $\text{Diff}(M)$ as an infinite dimensional Lie group; there is a unique 1-parameter subgroup defined by an element $X \in \Gamma(TM)$ of the "Lie algebra" of this group)

Comment: Balarka, I think this $X$ will not satisfy $\phi_t=\exp (X_t )$ in general.